# Blazor : Application crash after published in IIS server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a problem with my application after deployment to IIS, Application is written in .NET core version 3.1.

After publishing, I have an error with open.iconic-bootstrap.css and application crashes.

[image: BlazorServer IIS]

The same application when run on local gives an error but still works:
[image: LocalRun]

When I comment .script src="_framework/blazor.server.js". ./script. in `_host.cshtml`
implemented buttons don't work but the application runs with no crash.

Comment: Note: It may be useful to include the error messages as code in your post, since the text will be searchable.